# How to get a value from a numberfield and set it into a grid numbercolumn

Tags: extjs, grid, getvalue

Is it possible to get a number value from a number field and set it into a number column in a grid for every single row, substituting the values sent from the store ?

The number field would be located in a form above the grid. So it would be getting the number from that field and put it into a column in the grid sustituting any value that may be in that column with the new one I am getting from the number field in the form.

Comment: Where is number field located inside grid ? Please provide more details.

Comment: @Tejas The number field would be located in a form above the grid. So it would be getting the number from that field and put it into a column in the grid sustituting any value that may be in that column with the new one I am getting from the number field in the form.

Answer (score 0):

First get the numberfield value with Ext.getCmp, component.down, etc.

Then, get the grid reference and loop over the store like this:

```
 YOURGRID.getStore().data.items.forEach(dictionaryItem => dictionaryItem.data.YOURATTRIBUTE = NEWVALUE);
```

Comment: Better solution is: `YOURGRID.getStore().each(function (rec) { rec.set(YOURATTRIBUTE, NEWVALUE);});` instead of overwriting private parameters.